# Updating my resume on GitHub

Tags: git, pdf, github

I am using GitHub pages to host my personal website for a while.  Today, I updated my resume and wish to push it to the remote repository.

My original resume was named 'Resume.pdf'.  My new updated Resume is again called 'Resume.pdf' and I have placed it in my local repository replacing the original one.  Other than this I have made no other change.  But now my Git Shell refuses to acknowledge that there have been any updates to my local repository (and understandably so since its a .pdf file).  So, when I run the `git status` command, it doesn't show anything to be added and consequently nothing to be committed either.

I was wondering if there is some way in which I could forcefully commit and push the new resume.  Also, would such a forceful commit be valid (from an integrity standpoint)?

Comment: Sounds strange since git know to manage binaries. If I were, I would double check that it is the updated resume your are trying to push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check if that file is not ignored:

```
git check-ignore -v -- Resume.pdf
```

If could be added with `git add -f -- Resume.pdf`.